# Two input forms side-by-side programatically via JavaScript & d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Though I've looked at a lot of similar questions, and tried a number of variations, I can't get these two input forms side-by-side.  No doubt I've missed the one combo that would work in this case.  Suggestions appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gw13cww0/)

```
#CURSOR_TB {
  display: inline;
}

#OFFSET_SLIDER {
  display: inline;
}

<div id = "controls"> </div>

var setupCursorTextBox = function() {
  var S1;
  S1 = d3.select("#controls")
    .append("form")
    .append("label")
    .text("cursor ")
    .insert("input")
    .attr({
        type: "text",
        id: "CURSOR_TB",
        class: "cursor",
        value: ""
    })
} // End of setupCursorTextBox

var setupSliders = function() {
  var S1;
  S1 = d3.select("#controls")
    .append("form")
    .append("label")
    .text("offset ")
    .insert("input")
    .attr({
        type: "range",
        id: "OFFSET_SLIDER",
        class: "slider",
        min: 0.0,
        max: 100.0,
        value: 0.0,
    })
} // End of setupSliders

setupCursorTextBox();
setupSliders();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a line of CSS:

```
form { display: inline-block; }
```

Or for each form add an inline styling:

```
.append("form")
.style("display", "inline-block")
  .append("label")
  //... etc
```

Or for each form add a class that defines the same property:

```
// in CSS: .inline-form { display: 'inline-block' }
.append("form")
.attr("class", "inline-form")
  .append("label")
  //... etc
```

Comment: Thanks.  I used the first option.  I did not think/had not tried to mess with the form as a whole.

Comment: well if you don't want to affect every forms of your app but just these the other 2 solutions are better, otherwise indeed the first is simpler.